# Can't cross-compile from linux 64 bit to linux 32

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, cairo

I have to compile libcairo-1.14.2 in linux in 32 but format, on a 64 bit linux system.

I have tried the following commands:

```
# ./autogen.sh --host = i386-pc-linux-gnu --build = i386-linux CFLAGS = -m32
# ./configure --prefix = "/usr/work/libcairo-1.14.2/compiled/" --host = i386-pc-linux-gnu --build = i386-linux CFLAGS = "-m32 -O"
```

but, after I run make, the compilation returns me as an error:

```
In file included from cairo-xlib-private.h: 40: 0,
                 from cairo-xlib-display.c: 40:
cairo-xlib-xrender-private.h: 106: 16: error: redefinition of 'struct _XLinearGradient'
 typedef struct _XLinearGradient {
                ^
In file included from cairo-xlib-xrender.h: 45: 0,
                 from cairo-xlib-xrender-private.h: 53,
                 from cairo-xlib-private.h: 40,
                 from cairo-xlib-display.c: 40:
/usr/include/X11/extensions/Xrender.h:186:16: note: originally defined here
 typedef struct _XLinearGradient {
                ^
In file included from cairo-xlib-private.h: 40: 0,
                 from cairo-xlib-display.c: 40:
cairo-xlib-xrender-private.h: 109: 3: error: conflicting types for 'XLinearGradient'
 } XLinearGradient; 

...
```

Comment: I need the source as the program I am developing must work both on a RHEL 6.4 clone and on RHEL 7.9 and if I had to install cairo 1.14.2 rpm on RHEL 6.4 I would have to update the whole system and I cannot do it

Comment: ? So what you want for EL6 is a cairo-1.14.2 compiled with the ~12 EL6 cairo dependencies, and their dependencies ?...... Binary example from CentOS 6.10-i686 : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16uBDTegDZFLvMpvcug7uuPSPXn7R5BZU?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I have installed the following packages, in the 32-bit version, and now I can compile:

```
# yum install libX11-devel.i686
# yum install libXext-devel.i686
# yum install libXrender-devel.i686
# yum install freetype-devel.i686
# yum install pixman-devel.i686
# yum install fontconfig-devel.i686
# yum install libpng-devel.i686
# yum install libpng12-devel.i686
# yum install libxcb-devel.i686
# yum install glib2-devel.i686
# yum install librsvg2-devel.i686 librsvg2.i686
# yum install gdk-pixbuf2-devel.i686
# yum install pango-devel.i686
# yum install gtk2-devel.i686
```